# Javascript Regex Replace Without Resolving Backreference

Tags: javascript, escaping, backreference

I'm trying to replace a password token `[**PASSWORD**]` in a string with the password and am having trouble with passwords that contain the string `$&`.

For example:

```
var re = new RegExp('(?:\\[\\*\\*PASSWORD\\*\\*\\])', 'g');
'Your temporary password is: [**PASSWORD**]'.replace(re, 'B9z3$&dd');
```

I want the output to be `Your temporary password is: B9z3$&dd`, but instead the `$&` is resolving the backreference to `[**PASSWORD**]` which makes the output `Your temporary password is: B9z3[**PASSWORD**]dd`

How can I prevent Javascript from resolving the backreference and simply insert the text as-is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the $ in your replacement string doubling it: `B9z3$$&dd`.

Here's a demo:

```js
result = 'Your temporary password is: [**PASSWORD**]'.replace(/\[\*\*PASSWORD\*\*\]/mg, "B9z3$$&dd");

console.log(result);
```